# My datagridview binded with MS Access Database displays wrong time format

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview, datetime-format

I am trying to print pdf report using itextsharp pdf and all the values are correct except the values from column "Date" and "Time".
The date and time is displayed in a format like "dd/MM/yyyy tt hh:mm:ss" **for eg. Date is: 08/10/2021 AM 12:00:00 and Time is: 30/12/1899 AM 07:46:37.**

I have done everything mentioned below:

1. Inserting the date value from the datetimepicker as datetimepicker.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") and time value to be DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
2. My datatype for Date and Time column in MS Access database is Date/Time

My database is showing correct formatted value and datagridview has incorrect format of Time column and generated pdf report have incorrect date and time format. My only question is how can this be possible as database consist of correct data but after displaying it in datagridview the format changes and even after printing it. Below I have attached images that will help you get the scenario.

Datatype for the column from database↓

[image: Datatype]

Values in database↓

[image: Data]

Values in Datagridview↓

[image: Datagridview]

Comment: Look at the [DataGridColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/default-cell-styles-datagridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:~:text=%20To%20set%20default%20styles%20for%20cells%20in,properties%2C%20using%20the%20Preview%20pane%20to...%20More%20)

Comment: @Steve It did changed the cell style for both columns but when I print the values of cell it returns long format.

Comment: A DateTime value has no format. You take the value and then apply a formatting option available in the tool used to display the date. At the same time when you retrieve the DateTime value you don't get back any particular display format. Again is the tool used to display that applies formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to set the DefaultStyle property like this

```
dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
```

Or set it in the designer, whatever you like most.

In your database your `Time` column seems to have only a time value, but it has not. It uses the lowest possible date value, which is 30/12/1899 for an Access Database.
This happens when you only feed that column with a time, and no date. Acces (and other databases also) will simply use their lowest possible date value to fill up the missing date value.
The DataGridView therefor has no choice but to also show the date along with its time.

The property above will simply instruct the DataGridView to not show the date part, only the time part.

If you need to display the time in code in C#, you could use this

```
YourDateTimeVariable.ToString("T");
```

But, since you are storing both `date` and `time` in datetime columns, why do you store them seperate ?
You could just store them in one column, and show/use only the part you need.

**EDIT**
to respond to the code you posted in the comments (please add this code in your question, not in the comments)

change this

```
invoicesDatagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString())
```

into this

```
((datetime)invoicesDatagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString("T"))
```

in case this column can by null you will need some extra checks to avoid cast errors.
Also, the format in the GridCell willl never be used in a ToString(), you are doing the ToString() on the value, not on the display text.
Try the code above to fix this

**EDIT**
To respond to your comment below:

*Printing code is not the point. I just want to know that how can datagridview cell value and print value be of different format –
karan ugale*

By setting the DefaultCellStyle you tell the DataGridView what format to use to display the value. When you print this value with your own code using ToString(), how on earth should this ToString() know of the DefaultCellStyle setting ? The print code with ToString() has absolutly no connection with the DataGridView, you just pass it the value nothing more.

Look at this example

```
invoicesDatagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString())
```

this can be written like this

```
var someValue = invoicesDatagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
someValue.ToString();
```

now tell me, how should someValue.ToString() know of any format ?

Comment: I changed the default cell style format and datagridview did changed the values format as desired but still when I print the value from date and time it prints long format.

Comment: how do you print the data ? Can you show the code how you print the data

Comment: This is the code I use to display the columns value 
"MessageBox.Show("Date: " + invoicesDatagridview.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "\nTime: " + invoicesDatagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());"
Which have a format of value displayed in the cell to be "dd/MM/yyyy" format but returns the value formatted "dd/MM/yyyy tt hh:mm:ss" like this. @GuidoG

Comment: Please edit your question and add this code there, not in the comments. People that read your question will not go thru all the comments to find relevant information, it should be in the question, not in the comments

Comment: Printing code is not the point. I just want to know that how can datagridview cell value and print value be of different format

Comment: because displaying a value in a datagridview cell uses different code then you are using to print it. In both you will have to say what format to use, that is all there is to it

Comment: I edited my answer to respond on your last comment

Comment: So you mean to say that if datagridview has some value in a fixed format for eg. 19/09/21 and if I demanded the value using value.ToString() then it will display me some other formatted value?

Comment: Yes the value.ToString() will not display with the same format than the datagridview will do. The datagridview uses it's own formatting, which can be overriden by setting the DefaultCellStyle. And value.ToString() has absolutly nothing at all to do with the datagridview, it just displays whatever is in value with his own format, which you can again override. They are both complete different things, The datagrid view uses its own code to show the content of value, and the value.ToString() also uses its own code to display it. There is no relation between them

Comment: If I give you some text and ask you to display it, and I give the same text to someone else, why would this someone else display it in the same way you would ?

Comment: Yes that makes sense!
So here I'm trying to print the datagridview using itextsharp and below is the code I'm using which takes the whole datagridview values and fill in the pdf
Code:

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in invoicesDatagridview.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
                }
            }

Comment: This is difficult when you keep putting relevant information and code into comments. Please, edit your question and put this information there. I cannot respond to this until this information is in your question and not in a comment

Answer (score 0):

The epoc of data type *Date* in Access is 1899-12-30, and as you display both date and time, that date is displayed as well.

In .Net you can apply the format string "T" to display *hour-minute-second* only. For example:

```cs
DateTime time = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 8, 12, 16);
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("T"));
// 08:12:16
```